# substract using activecell.offset

Tags: vba, offset

my lastrow is (315) - in the below code i need help in the last line (i am trying to do (sum of col H) - (sum of col J) by using activecell-offset in col k

```
''Totals''
Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Formula = "=activecell.offset(0,-3)-activecell.offset(0-1)"
```

Comment: you are picking 1 referenced cell (`K & LastRow`) and you are trying to substract your `ActiveCell` minus 3 columns from the `ActiveCell` minus 1 column. Your `ActiveCell`could be anywhere... what is your goal? Plus you are trying to use a formula with VBA code instead Excel Formula.

Comment: Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0) is my activecell i,e (K320)... i am trying to do =(H320-J320)

Comment: And there you are trying to do a Formula with cells from the same row, or you need the whole column?

Comment: Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0) is my activecell i,e (K320)... i am trying to do =(H320-J320) ...which are adjustcent cell to cell k320

Comment: You could use a R1C1 formula like "=RC[-3]-RC[-1]"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your last row becomes 315 and you have data on the 320 but you are looking for this:

```
Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Value = ActiveCell.offset(0,-3) - ActiveCell.offset(0-1)
```

Comment: Ok let me explain i have data from 2 to 315, but i am doing the sum in 320 for some reason.... in col k i am trying to the difference btwn two sum items.

Comment: This is not a formula though, isn't that what OP is requesting by the looks of his post?

Comment: And can't you do that with `SUM` or `SUMIF`? there is no need for VBA on a sample of 315 rows

Comment: @TimStack that's why I was just asking if he couldn't do a formula on the same sheet.

Comment: @TimStack.. I have already written code for the whole process, but i had doubt on this piece. sorry if i have confused you both.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Formula = "=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Address & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0 - 1).Address
```

This would work, but is not pretty. An alternative would be a static VBA solution such as Damian's answer.

Furthermore, I would advise you to refer to the correct workbook and -sheet. If you were to omit this, the VBA code would always refer to the active workbook/-sheet, something you often don't want.

E.g.

```
With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
     .Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Formula = "=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Address & "-" & ActiveCell.Offset(0 - 1).Address
End With
```

Next to that, referring to the active cell is also asking for trouble. Perhaps you are better off with referring to better defined ranges, such as

```
With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
     .Range("K" & LastRow).Offset(5, 0).Formula = "=" & .Cells(LastRow + 4, "K").Address & "-" & .Cells(LastRow, "J").Offset(0 - 1).Address  'Ranges randomly chosen 
End With
```

**EDIT**

Formulas are dynamic. In other words, their results change dynamically with values/ranges they refer to. Unless you code a Worksheet_Change event, the calculation below will not update if you change the values for which the sum is calculated. However, you don't always need calculations to be dynamic, so pick what you need. I am assuming your columns have headers.

```
With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    LROWJ = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    LROWH = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("H2:H" & LROWH)) - Application.Sum(.Range("J2:J" & LROWJ))
End With
```